# Regenerate missing package-lock.json file from node_modules

Tags: npm

The original developers for my project didn't commit the `package-lock.json` file, only the `package.json` file. I created my own `package-lock.json` file when I did `npm install`, but that was 5 years ago and I didn't realise at the time that I needed to check the file into Git because I stupidly assumed that the original developers knew what they were doing.

Now we have a second developer, plus I need to add a new package. Both of these things require that I have the "original" `package-lock.json` file.

Is there a way to reconstruct the `package-lock.json` file using npm from the contents of my `node_modules` directory which is now the only source of truth? I have looked at various answers and tried a few npm commands, such as `npm i --package-lock-only`, but that gave me a file as it would be created today, not the file based on my `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Can't you just check out a branch from 5 years ago, grab its `package.json`, then run `npm i --package-lock-only`?

Comment: @ThomasBui No, I get all the updated libraries that have been released in the last 5 years. It's almost the equivalent of running `npm i` five years ago, then running `npm up` today without saving the intervening file. While it doesn't actually change any libraries, I end up with a `package-lock.json` file that doesn't match most of my installed libraries. I mentioned that in my question too.

Comment: @ThomasBui Also, since this is the first time I'm changing the `package.json` file, the version from 5 years ago is the same as what I've got now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not finding an answer, I've spent the last two days writing some PHP code to do the job for me. The code is not complete, for example it assumes that the only production modules will be `angular` and `angular-ui-router` because I didn't need anything more complicated with my project. However, it's good enough to create an exact copy of the `package-lock.json` file, minus optional dependencies that weren't installed, because it can't resolve versions of packages it can't find.

The code was written to work, not necessarily to be easy to understand, so it might be a little opaque.

It's run with:

```php
<?php
$package_lock = new PackageLock();
// or
$package_lock = new PackageLock('path/to/packages');
```

The code:

```php
<?php
class PackageLock {
  protected const MY_PACKAGE = 'my-package';
  protected const MY_VERSION = '0.0.0';
  //
  protected const FILE_NAME = 'package-lock-recreated.json';
  protected const NODE_MODULES = 'node_modules';
  //
  protected array $modules = [];
  protected array $packages = [
    'name' => PackageLock::MY_PACKAGE,
    'version' => PackageLock::MY_VERSION,
    'lockfileVersion' => 1,
    'requires' => true,
  ];
  protected string $dir;

  public function __construct(string $dir = '.') {
    $this->dir = $dir;
    $this->packages['dependencies'] = $this->parse();

    file_put_contents(PackageLock::FILE_NAME, preg_replace('/^( +)\1/m', '$1', json_encode($this->packages, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)));
  }

  protected function parse(array $priors = []): array {
    $nm = PackageLock::NODE_MODULES;
    $requests = $priors;
    array_unshift($requests, '');

    $current_priors = $requests;
    $current_priors[] = '';
    $main_path = $this->dir . implode("/{$nm}/", $current_priors);
    $dir_pattern = $main_path . '*';
    $dirs = glob($dir_pattern);
    $current_dir = dirname($dir_pattern, 2);
    $dependencies = [];

    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
      $module_name = basename($dir);
      if (in_array($module_name, ['angular-moment-picker', 'json-loader', 'moment-timezone'])) {
        continue;
      }
      $this->modules[$dir] = json_decode(file_get_contents("{$dir}/package.json"));
    }

    foreach ($this->modules as $dir => $module) {
      if (strpos($dir, $main_path) !== 0) {
        continue;
      }

      $module_name = basename($dir);
      $dependencies[$module_name] = [
        'version' => $module->version,
        'resolved' => $module->_resolved,
        'integrity' => $module->_integrity,
      ];

      if (!$this->is_prod($module_name)) {
        $dependencies[$module_name]['dev'] = true;
      }

      if ($this->is_optional($main_path . $module_name)) {
        $dependencies[$module_name]['optional'] = true;
      }

      if (!empty($module->dependencies) && (array)$module->dependencies) {
        $dependencies[$module_name]['requires'] = $module->dependencies;
      }

      if (is_dir("{$current_dir}/{$nm}/{$module_name}/{$nm}")) {
        $dependencies[$module_name]['dependencies'] = $this->parse_dependencies($priors, $module_name);
      }
    }

    return $dependencies;
  }

  protected function is_prod($module_name): bool {
    return in_array($module_name, ['angular', 'angular-ui-router']);
  }

  protected function parse_dependencies(array $priors, string $module_name): array {
    $priors[] = $module_name;
    return $this->parse($priors);
  }

  protected function is_optional($key): bool {
    $module_name = basename($key);

    $is_optional = false;
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->modules)) {
      var_dump("Key does not exist: {$key}");
    }
    if ($this->modules[$key]) {
      foreach ($this->modules[$key]->_requiredBy as $parent_module_path) {
        if (in_array($parent_module_path, ['/', '#USER', '#DEV:/'])) {
          break;
        }
        $parent_module_path = $this->module_to_file_path($parent_module_path);

        if (array_key_exists($parent_module_path, $this->modules)) {
          $is_optional = $this->check_optional($parent_module_path, $module_name);
        }
        else {
          $file_name = "{$parent_module_path}/package.json";
          if (!file_exists($file_name)) {
            $is_optional = true;
          }
          else {
            $this->modules[$parent_module_path] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_name));
            $is_optional = $this->check_optional($parent_module_path, $module_name);
            unset($this->modules[$parent_module_path]);
          }
        }
        if (!$is_optional) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    return $is_optional;
  }

  protected function module_to_file_path($module_path): string {
    return $this->dir . str_replace('/', '/' . PackageLock::NODE_MODULES . '/', $module_path);
  }

  protected function check_optional(string $parent_module_path, $module_name): bool {
    if (
      !empty($this->modules[$parent_module_path]->optionalDependencies)
      && property_exists($this->modules[$parent_module_path]->optionalDependencies, $module_name)
    ) {
      $is_optional = true;
    }
    else {
      $is_optional = $this->is_optional($parent_module_path);
    }
    return $is_optional;
  }
}
```